# Does arduino uno have protection against burning a computer's usb port?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm currently using my computer's usb port for both charging and program uploading. However, I've heard cases that arduino was burned due to misconnected wires. So my question is, does arduino have protections for the computer's USB port? For example, if any short circuit happens, the board burns first and stops any data/electricity flow from/to the computer port so that we don't burn the computer's usb.

Comment: are you still here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. Both the computer USB port and arduino have some kind of protection.

Specifically your computer USB port usually has some good protection that you need not to worry about. In case you use a Chinese arduino unsure of its schematic, it would be a good practice to have an external USB port connected to your PC and to connect there the arduino.

The UNO unlike some other units has a resealable fuse on it, which is pretty a good way to protect your port, (that green led). In addition most if not all the arduino including UNO have a diode preventing wrong polarity to go into your PC.